# c# method to sort array without using any loop

Tags: java, c#

how can we write c-sharp method or java method to sort an array without using any loop, i tried following but not working correctly.

```
public static void sortArray(int[] array)
{
        int index = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        if (index < array.Length - 1)
        {
            if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
            {
                temp = array[index];
                array[index] = array[index + 1];
                array[index + 1] = temp;
            }



            index++;
            sortArray(array, index);

        }


    }
```

Comment: What you shown in your code is a **recursion**. If you need exactly a recursive sort please say it explicitly. "without any loop" seems to be rather confusing.

Comment: Yeah its recursion so could you tell me what's the problem in this code or if you've better solution to sort array without using a loop.

Comment: You said the code is "not working correctly", but it does not even compile. Is this an actual problem or you missed something in the posted code?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is a bit tricky, but it works finally.
C# code:

```
public static void sortArray(int[] array, int index)
{
    if (index < array.Length - 1)
    {
        if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
        {
            var temp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[index + 1];
            array[index + 1] = temp;
        }
        if (index > 0 && array[index] < array[index - 1]) sortArray(array, index - 1);
        else sortArray(array, index + 1);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
int[] arr = { 3000, 2000, 1000, 800, 100, 500, 200, 6, 8, 7, 17, 78, 22, };
sortArray(arr, 0);
```

This method sorts an array in-place, so `arr` itself will become sorted.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna This one is interecting after all :)

Comment: Thanks @DiligentKeyPresser. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) class to sort array in case of **c#**,

```
 Array.Sort(array);
```

And same in **Java** you can use [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to sort the `array` like this

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: i dont have to use built in functions, sorting should be done without functions or loop, means it has to be done manually.

Comment: @Jannik Yah It was, I was aware after answering.